# How to craft blood and hitpower gloves efficiently in Diablo II?

Tags: diablo-ii

I want to craft Hit Power Gloves and Blood Gloves. I know for Hit Power Gloves that you don't want the Affixlevel of the Gloves too high and I suppose the same thing applies to Blood Gloves. The reason for that is that the highest level affixes are useless (like 30 Frostarrow charges for example) and therefore you have to pay attention to the item level of the gloves.

I have heard that people get specific levels on characters and gambmle or (regular-) buy the gloves from the vendors. I would prefer always elite gloves if possible. But I would go with exceptional gloves, if you can't really buy/gamble them from vendors. Anyone has some insight on this? What is the character level you need to buy/gamble those gloves? Or do you actually need to farm specific areas with an area level of 70 or 75 for example to find them (this is very impractical and would take a lot of time farming areas where you can't find anything that useful besides crafting materials and some midgear stuff).

Edit: My goal is to get both types of gloves with maximum number of affixes with no "useless" affixes. So besides the fixed stats I'm looking for resistances, attack speed, attack rating, +2 to java/bow skills, strenght, dex, vita, % to cast frost nova when struck

Comment: Man, I am like 4/4 out of your Diablo 2 questions, but this one is so hard. Crafting these kinds of gloves is complicated and takes extreme luck. The only thing I can even recommend is something like this [link](https://forums.d2jsp.org/topic.php?t=30598890)

Comment: Hah ur the only one on the whole site trying to answer those questions. TBH I can figure this out myself, just lazy :)

Comment: It's not the easiest thing in the world, so crafting was SO niche because uniques and runewords were actually powerful in D2

Comment: Gotta know the itemlevels of items when buying items, then calculate the affixlevel after craft and there is a list on indiablo.de where you can see all the affixes and affixlevels on any item.

Comment: well uniques kinda suck now, runewords are too good

Comment: @FoxMcCloud I have been enjoying and also trying to contribute to these D2 questions as well, but man, it's ones like this that make me realize how long it has actually been since I've played regularly... I remember gambling gloves from Gheed for this exact purpose, but the full details of item level and crafting requirements has been lost with time...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok the solution took longer than I expected. You can read the solution for the results only or the explanation that comes after that.

---

### Conclusion:

There are two good possiblities for using specific characters for crafting. You can either gamble your gloves or farm them in level 85 areas like the Chaos Sanctuary for example.

**Gambling (Hell):**
A character that has a **level of 82** can gamble and craft the gloves and will be in the perfect affix range. I considered only exceptional and elite gloves for that.

**Finding crafting gloves in 84 + 85 areas:**
When monsters drop items your characters level is not important. So you can farm those areas with your strong characters and collect them. But you need to craft with a **level 75** character for best results. You can actually use any item with an item level from 84 to 93, if you are using a level 75 character.

If you want to include normal gloves into your craft you will need another character around level 55. This is not really worth it IMO.

---

You could probably calculate all possible answers with the help of statistics and probability. But I'll go for a pragmatic approach. I want to find a character level that works.

**Blood Gloves:**
Nef-Rune + Magic Jewel + Perfect Ruby + Heavy Gloves or Sharkskin Gloves or Vampirebone Gloves

**Hit Power Gloves:**
Ort-Rune + Magic Jewel + Perfect Sapphire + Chain Gloves or Heavy Bracers or Vambraces

If you really don't care about the defense of the gloves, you can use any glove type to craft, but I find that you should only craft exceptional or elite gloves (Sharkskin Gloves, Vampirebone gloves, Heavy bracers, Vampbracers). One thing to mention in advance is that you cannot buy exceptional or elite gloves. In fact you can't find any of the needed gloves in hell difficulty (vendors). So only thing you can buy are normal type gloves in nightmare difficulty. This method is very fast and very easy to calculate, because the bought gloves will always have the item level of `clvl + 5`. But again: the defense of normal gloves is extremely low.

So now that we know what we want, where do we find those gloves? You can buy them from vendors, gamble them from vendors or find them in the game. Although it takes longer to find the items in the game, you can know the exact item level of the gloves and predict exactly, if the gloves are material for a perfect craft.

Firstly we want the item level of the resulting craft to be higher than 71 (inclusive). This  will guarante a perfect quantity of number of affixes. Which is 4, according to this:

> [Link: Crafting Handbook](https://forums.d2jsp.org/topic.php?t=30598890)
> Ilvls 1-30: 4 affixes (20 %), 3 affixes (20 %), 2 affixes (20 %), 1 affix (40 %)
> Ilvls 31-50: 4 affixes (20 %), 3 affixes (20 %), 2 affixes (60 %)
> Ilvls 51-70: 4 affixes (20 %), 3 affixes (80 %)
> Ilvls 71+: 4 affixes (100 %)

What is most important to us is the affixlevel on the item. The algorithm to calculate the affixlevel will be posted, but it depends highly on the quality level of the item. The problem with that is that the you can use 3 types of gloves for each crafting recipie, which all have very spread out quality levels.

> Heavy Gloves (qlvl 7)
> Sharkskin Gloves (qlvl 39)
> Vampirebone Gloves (qlvl 63)
> Chain Gloves (qlvl 12)
> Heavy Bracers (qlvl 43)
> Vambraces (qlvl 69)

I suggest to have one or more characters that you don't play and use simply for crafting to have consistent results. But the spread out quality level won't make it simple: you cannot just have one character and craft all the gloves. You need different characters with different levels. I will only look at crafting exceptional and elite gloves, gambled from vendors or found in area level 85 (f.e. River Of Flame, Pits, Ancient Tunnels ...). The possible level spread for the magic item level for gambling items from vendors is: `[min;max] = [clvl-5 ; clvl+4]`. In level 85 areas you can farm for the best items in the game and know the item level of gloves for sure. It's level 85 from normal monsters, level 87 from champions or level 88 from elite monsters.

Now let's see the affixes we want or don't want. [This](https://diablo3.ingame.de/diablodb/affix_display.php?lang=de&version=lod&patch=111&type=glov&item=schwere%20Armschienen&mlvl=0&qlvl=43&ilvl=-1&sortby=lvl) german website shows the tables of the affix levels for gloves. The good thing is that Hitpower Gloves and Blood Gloves have the same affixes and affixlevels for all types of gloves (normal, exc, elt). The last affix that we want has an affix level of 59. All the affixes after level 59 are useless and the next one starts from affixlevel 63. So this means that the optimal affixlevel that we want has the range of `[59 ; 62]`. But the cool thing is that the next affix after that has an affixlevel of 68. And the rarity of that affix is very low, so I think that it's statistically better to include the level 63 affix. So this means that our optimal range is `[59 ; 67]`. This is a way bigger range and makes it easier to hit that with our craft. Now comes the algorithm for calculating the affix level. Here is the java code for that:

```
    public static double calculateAffixLevel(double characterLevel, double magicItemLevel, double magicItemQualityLevel)
{
    double craftedItemLevel, affixLevel;
    craftedItemLevel = Math.floor(0.5 * characterLevel) + Math.floor(0.5 * magicItemLevel);
    
    if (craftedItemLevel > 99)
    {
        craftedItemLevel = 99; // this can't really happen for crafting gloves!
    }
    
    if (magicItemQualityLevel > craftedItemLevel)
    {
        craftedItemLevel = magicItemQualityLevel;
    }
    
    if (craftedItemLevel < (99 - Math.floor(0.5 * magicItemQualityLevel)))
    {
        affixLevel = craftedItemLevel - Math.floor(0.5 * magicItemQualityLevel);
    }
    else
    {
        affixLevel = (craftedItemLevel * 2) - 99;
    }
    
    return affixLevel;
}
```

Again gambling items can have an item level of a range of 9 levels. And this can influence the resulting affixlevel. So we need a character level that gives us our desired affix level with any of the 9 levels in the range of gambling. And one charcter level that works for nearly all exceptional and elite gloves is 82 (more to that later). The possible item levels from gambling are 77 to 86 and they all result in an affix level of `[59 ; 67]`.

The second scenario is finding the gloves in level 85 areas. The possible item level of the gloves can be from 85 to 88 in those areas. So we are again looking for a character level that always gives us the affix level in the optimal range. And this level through testing is level 75.

Here are all the area levels that work for a level 75  character. Any monster that you kill in these areas can drop exceptional or elite gloves for crafting:

> [Area Level Diablo Wiki](https://diablo2.diablowiki.net/Area_Level)
> LV    LEVELNAME
> 85    The Worldstone Keep Level 1
> 85    The Worldstone Keep Level 2
> 85    The Worldstone Keep Level 3
> 85    Throne of Destruction
> 84    Halls of Vaught
> 84    Halls of Death's Calling (Halls of Pain)
> 85    Chaos Sanctuary
> 85    River of Flame
> 84    City of the Damned
> 85    Disused Reliquary
> 85    Ruined Fane
> 85    Forgotten Temple
> 84    Forgotten Reliquary
> 84    Disused Fane
> 84    Ruined Temple
> 84    Sewers Level 1 + 2 (Act 3)
> 85    Ancient Tunnels
> 85    Maggot Lair Level 3
> 84    Maggot Lair Level 1 + 2
> 85    Mausoleum
> 85    The Pit

Here are the outputs for the algorithm with changed the different parameters. So again: we are looking for affixlevels in a range from 59 to 67 (inclusive). The output show the affixlevel of the gloves for crafting. Since we are looking at a range of possible item levels, the output shows all affix levels that come out of them.

**Gambling (gambling + crafting with a level 82 character):**
Sharkskin Gloves (qlvl 39): [60.0, 61.0, 61.0, 63.0, 63.0, 65.0, 65.0, 67.0, 67.0, 69.0]
Vampirebone Gloves (qlvl 63): [59.0, 61.0, 61.0, 63.0, 63.0, 65.0, 65.0, 67.0, 67.0, 69.0]
Heavy Bracers (qlvl 43): [59.0, 61.0, 61.0, 63.0, 63.0, 65.0, 65.0, 67.0, 67.0, 69.0]
Vambraces (qlvl 69): [59.0, 61.0, 61.0, 63.0, 63.0, 65.0, 65.0, 67.0, 67.0, 69.0]
The only case where the resulting affix level exceeds our desired range is for heavy bracers and vampbracers with an ilvl of 86. This is quite a rare case with a chance of 1/9 for either of those items. So still level 82 is very good.

**Finding items in level 84 + 85 areas (crafting with a lvl 75 character):**
Sharkskin Gloves (qlvl 39): [60.0, 61.0, 61.0, 63.0]
Vampirebone Gloves (qlvl 63): [59.0, 61.0, 61.0, 63.0]
Heavy Bracers (qlvl 43): [59.0, 61.0, 61.0, 63.0]
Vambraces (qlvl 69): [59.0, 61.0, 61.0, 63.0]

**Conclusion:** See top of the post!

Comment: Ya that's insane. +1

Comment: @FoxMcCloud Yeah its really incredible how much complexity you can go into with this game :D